# Test Windows AD Integration on a workgroup machine

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is there a dev aid that can simulate Windows AD on a non-domain machine, aka my dev laptop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, to a certain degree, [Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705886%28VS.85%29.aspx) (AD LDS - formerly known as AD/AM), can do this.

It's a Windows service that you can install, start and stop on a dev machine and that works very closely like the "real" Active Directory.

There are some limitations - see the MSDN docs for details.

Marc

UPDATE: AD LDS comes with Win Server 2003 R2 and Win Server 2008, or can be downloaded under its old name AD/AM (Active Directory/Application Mode) for Windows XP and WinServer 2003 from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9688F8B9-1034-4EF6-A3E5-2A2A57B5C8E4&displaylang=en

Comment: Thanks.  As usual, the biggest limitations are in the MSDN docs, which say nothing about where to get AD LDS.  It seems to come with Server 2008, which I'm not about to download over 3G.  However, it did point me to ADAM, which is available for download.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do.  If you just want to do LDAP queries then ADAM/ADLDS will do the trick.  If you need the security-related aspects of AD, then no.

One possible solution is to run Virtual PC or VMware and on the laptop and have a virtualised workstation to use for your AD integration testing.  In that case, I might consider also going for 2008 (R2?) on the laptop and using Hyper-V.